# How To Get Variables Submitted by AJAX Using PHP Correctly?

Tags: php, ajax

I have this ajax/jquery code :

```
var headline = $("input#headline").val();
var subheadline = $("textarea#subheadline").val();
var pics = $("input#pics").val();   
var dataString = 'headline='+ headline + '&subheadline=' + subheadline + '&pics=' + pics;

$(".save-notice").hide();
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "web-block/forms/process-001.php",
data: dataString,
success: function() {             
$(".save-notice").show();
$(this).parents(".manage-content-wrap").next(".ribbon-content").fadeIn();
}  
});
```

on the other side, I have this HTML form :

```
<form action="" id="select-block" class="general-form">
<div class="input-wrap">
    <input class="clearme" name="Headline" value="<?php echo $Headline;?>" id="headline"/>
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
    <textarea class="clearme" name="Sub-Headline" id="subheadline"><?php echo $SubHeadline;?></textarea>
</div>
<label>Bottom Left Image</label>
<div class="up-mask">
    <span class="file-wrapper">
      <input type="file" name="Pics" class="photo" id="pics" />
      <span class="button">
         <span class="default-txt">Upload Photo</span>
      </span>
    </span>
</div><!-- .up-mask -->

<input type="hidden" name="Key" value="<?php echo $Key;?>"/>
<input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="SAVE" />
<span class="save-notice">Your changed has been saved!</span>
</form>
```

as you can see process-001.php is the file which process all variables from HTML form. but I have difficulties to 'catch' `$Headline` and `$SubHeadline` submitted by that form, which actually 'manipulates' by Ajax too...

I tried using this code on process-001.php :

```
$Headline = $_POST['Headline'];
$SubHeadline = $_POST['Sub-Headline'];
```

but seems that those variables are empty... how to get variables submitted by AJAX correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`headline` and `Headline` are not the same key.  Your keys need to match *exactly*.

Also, as building the strings by hand can become extremely tricky very quickly, you may want to consider using an object literal or `serialize()`:

```
data: {
    'foo': 'bar',
    'baz': [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Would have `$_POST['foo'] === 'bar'` and `$_POST['baz'] === array(1, 2, 3)`

You also shouldn't assume that any kind of inputs exist:

```
$headline = (isset($_POST['headline'])) ? $_POST['headline'] : null;
```

Otherwise you can get index undefined notices.

Also, since you're not using any of the options that `$.post` doesn't expose, you could just use `$.post` for shorthand:

```
$.post("web-block/forms/process-001.php", {
    data: $("#select-block").serialize(),
    function() {             
        $(".save-notice").show();
        $(this).parents(".manage-content-wrap").next(".ribbon-content").fadeIn();
    }  
});
```

Or:

```
$.post("web-block/forms/process-001.php", {
    data: {
        Headline: $("#headline").val(), //input#headline is redundant -- getting a node by ID is extremely efficent; getting by tag is not
        'Sub-Headline': $("#subheadline").val()
    },
    function() {             
        $(".save-notice").show();
        $(this).parents(".manage-content-wrap").next(".ribbon-content").fadeIn();
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try datastream like

```
var dataString = {
                   headline: headline,
                   subheadline: subheadline,
                   pics:pics
                };
```

for fatching in php you need to use

$Headline = $_POST['headline'];

$SubHeadline = $_POST['subheadline'];

and it will work fine

Comment: ...this still wouldn't work because he requests `$_POST['Headline']`.

Comment: @Ben he has created dataString with headline. So, in post they will receive using headline only.

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST` variables are case-sensitive - your variables on the ajax side are lowercase, the PHP side is capitalized.

Comment: thanks bro, I didn't realize I made some typo here... thanks again!

Comment: Welcome, welcome, although @Corbin had me by 10 seconds...and a series of edits with increasingly helpful information ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that process-001.php is ever requested? Because, one of the possibilities is that when you click the submit button, the wrapping form has been submitted with empty action.

A safer way is

```
<input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="SAVE" onclick="return false;" />
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('form#select-block input:submit').click(function() {
  // ajax goes here
});
</script>
```